# angular app hosted on azure showing blank page

Tags: angular, azure

I have published my 'dist' folder to azure and verified it under site\wwwroot.

But the site is showing a blank page when loading.

There is no error in browser console.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well. What error is showing when hit "F12". I assume there are JavaScript errors in the console

Comment: no error in console. I have updated the question with images.

Comment: For me it seems your app has no content. How did you create the dist folder? ng build —prod ?

Comment: My co-worker is experiencing this, but it's probably not the same issue. She was the only one experiencing this on azurewebsites but the rest of the team can run the website fine.